# How does return statement return values in recursive functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, return

Can someone please explain me how this recursive function works. I can't understand how the values are returned in call stack. Could you please explain with some graphics, representing the execution contexts. It would be better if you can explain the way as explained in the Udemy course JavaScript-understanding the weird parts.

```
function findSolution(target) {

    function find(start, history) {
        if (start == target)
            return history;
        else if (start > target)
           return null;
        else
            return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5) ") || find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3) ");
    }

return find(1, "1");
}
console.log(findSolution(13));
```

Comment: You can check this video, at the exact time there is an animation https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ?t=326

Comment: One key to understanding recursion is this: It's not special. If you understand how `function three() { return one(two()); }` works, you understand how `function recurse(val) { return val == 0 ? 0 : 1 + recurse(val - 1); }` works.

Comment: If you're having trouble understanding recursion (which is entirely understandable!) I suggest starting with a simpler recursive function, such as the one in my comment above, and using the debugger built into your IDE or browser to step through, look at the call stack, etc. The debugger provides a *live* diagram of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know how the values are returned at every function execution.

Comment: @AarizzzHakim: A good debugger will tell you that. If the debugger you're using is only so-so, just assign the value to a local variable before returning it, and you'll be able to see it.

Comment: @AarizzzHakim If you downvote my answer no matters, but please review answer careful I have updated my answer with proper explanation.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a recursive function with two exit conditions, one for a found result, where the start and target value is equal, this returns the history and one where the start value is greater than the target value, which returns `null` for not found result.

The recursive machanis is to branch the calling of the function in two direction, one with adding fice, the other one by multiplying the value by three.

The branching takes place with a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()), which means if the first branch returns a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) result, this result is taken and the other branch is never called. If the first branch returns `null`, a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, the second branch is called.

What you finally get is a tree with branches and tests.

```
      1          level 0
    /   \
  2       5      level 1
 / \     / \
3   4   6   7    level 2
```

That means, with the first call, it starts with 1 and goes if necessary to 2 and 3 and so on.

To get an idea, you could add a level variable to a console.log and watch what is going in every level.

> ```
> level, start, history                         action
> --------------------------------------------  ----------------
> 0 1 1                                         check next level
>     1 6 (1 + 5)                               check next level
>         2 11 ((1 + 5)  + 5)                   check next level
>             3 16 (((1 + 5)  + 5)  + 5)        null
>             3 33 (((1 + 5)  + 5)  * 3)        null
>         2 18 ((1 + 5)  * 3)                   null
>     1 3 (1 * 3)                               check next level
>         2 8 ((1 * 3)  + 5)                    check next level
>             3 13 (((1 * 3)  + 5)  + 5)        found
>
> (((1 * 3)  + 5)  + 5)                         result
> ```

```js
function findSolution(target) {

    function find(start, history, level) {
        level = level || 0;
        console.log(level, start, history);
        if (start == target) return history;            // exit condition 1 (found)
        if (start > target) return null;                // exit condition 2 (not found)
        return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5) ", level + 1) ||
               find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3) ", level + 1);
    }

    return find(1, "1");
}
console.log(findSolution(13));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, very nice of you. Could you please tell me when null is returned, how does it move to  the right of the Logical OR and chooses to multiply the "start" by 3. I am confused, if it may return the null to the main function and stop the recursion.

Comment: `null` with a logical OR forces the next expression to evaluate. if you have `null || 42`, you get the answer.

Comment: @AarizzzHakim Detail blog about short circuit evaluation http://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/short-circuit-evaluation-in-js/

Comment: Nice hack using `.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }` was wondering why CSS was needed here till I realised it styled the console widget to be full screen

Answer (score 0):

Have tried mapping out a few execution cases for your reference below. I guess the only tricky part here is the line `return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5) ") || find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3) ");`

What may not be obvious is that `||` is called the [short circuit or in JS](http://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/short-circuit-evaluation-in-js/). This means that if we do `var x = a || b` `b` is evaluated ONLY if `a` is not truthy.

In the context of your question, the mentioned line is essentially saying "Try going down the path of adding 5 and ONLY IF THIS FAILS (ie, returns null) Try going down the path of multiplying 3.

The recursive function `find` here has essentially three cases:

1. `start == target` is true, which means we have reached the end of recursion with a solution. This returns the history string
2. `start > target` is true, which means we have overshot the target, return with null to indicate that this path does not lead to the solution
3. Neither of the two cases are valid. `Try going down the path of adding 5`. If that doesn't work (we get back null), `try going down the path of multiplying 3`.

Sample Cases:

```
findSolution(0) //target=0
    find(1, "1") //This goes to Case 3
        find(1+5,"(1 + 5)") || find(1*3,"(1 * 3)")
            find(1+5,"(1 + 5)") // This is a Case 2, returns null, try multiplying by 3 now
            find(1*3,"(1 * 3)") // This is Case 2 again, returns null
        null || null //Both paths lead to null, stop recursing, return null
    null
null



findSolution(1) //target=1
    find(1,"1") // This leads to the case 1. Return the history string
    "1"
"1"

findSolution(3) //target = 3
    find(1,"1") //This leads to case 3
        find(1+3,"(1 + 5)") || find(1*3,"(1 * 3)")
            find(1+5,"(1 + 5)") // This is a Case 2, returns null, try multiplying by 3 now
            find(1*3, "(1 * 3)") // This is a case 1, return History string, recursion ends
        null || "(1 * 3)"
    "(1 * 3)"
"(1 * 3)"

findSolution(8) //target=8
    find(1,"1") //This leads to case 3
        find(1+5,"(1 + 5)") || find(1*3,"(1 * 3)") // Evaluate lhs first
            find(1+5,"(1 + 5)") // This is a case 3 scenario again
                find(6 + 5,"((1 + 5) + 5)") || find(6 * 3, "((1 + 5) * 3)")
                    find(6 + 5,"((1 + 5) + 5)") // Case 2, returns null
                    find(6 * 3, "((1 + 5) * 3)") // Case 2, returns null
                null || null //Going down the add 5 path failed here, try multiplying 3
            find(1*3,"(1 * 3)") // This is a case 3
                find(3 + 5, "((1*3)+5)") || find(3 * 3, "((1 * 3) * 3")
                    find(8,"((1*3)+5)")  // This is case 1, recursion ends, return history
                    "((1*3)+5)"
                "((1*3)+5)" || find(..) //LHS evaluated to true, no need to do rhs
            "((1*3)+5)"
        "((1*3)+5)"
    "((1*3)+5)"
"((1*3)+5)"
```

Answer (score -1):

In a simple term,

A recursive function is a function that calls itself during its execution. This enables the function to repeat itself several times, outputting the result and the end of each iteration.

Recursive functions are common in computer science because they allow programmers to write efficient programs using a minimal amount of code.

The downside is that they can cause infinite loops and other unexpected results if not written properly.

Recursive function development and execution is the variant based on complexity and nature of programming. If we simply assume about to increment value recursively for any value up to 100 then probably it may possible it is really very easy to implement but in the real programming environment, there are so many complex problems we face.

```js
function increment(start){    
    if(start < 100){
        start++;
        increment(start);     
        console.log(start);
    }else{
        console.log("value reached to 100");
    }
}
increment(0);
```

In this code, I have used increment function which increments by 1.

```
increment(0);
```

It is the function call where I can assign the initial value as 0 and it will start increment by 1 in the function.

```
if(start < 100){
    start++;
    increment(start);     
    console.log(start);
}else{
    console.log("value reached to 100");
}
```

I put comparison limit up to 100 so my function calls 101 times. Once it will reach to the limit and (start<100) condition false it will show else code message.

If I do not give the limit of 100 then it goes in infinite loop and javascript call stack maximum size exceeds error or browser may go in the infinite loop.

Hope my explanation may help you. Please review sites it will definitely helpful to you understands about recursion and recursive method.

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~calvin/cs110/RECURSION.html

https://javascript.info/recursion

Comment: Nice explanation on recursion. But I think OP was asking for explanation on how this particular function worked (as opposed to how recursion in general works)

Comment: @ChiragRavindra Probably you may wrong please read question carefully he does not ask specifically about the described recursive function but wants to know the concept of recursion.

Comment: From the question: "Can someone please explain me how this recursive function works." Not my downvote, cheers :)

Comment: @Chirag Ravindra Yes, brother you are right here. I was just asking how this function works. Not actually the concept of recursion.