# Recursive functions with || operator?

Tags: c++, recursion

So I was tinkering with `||` and `&&` operators with `return`. I developed an understanding by comparing `int` as for example `return 1 || 0;` `return 0 || 0;` that the program returns `1` or `0` in case of an `int` function and true or false in case of `bool` functions after comparing values.

Now I was writing a code to find path sum to given value using implementation of trees.

```
bool HasPathSum(ds::sn::BNode<int>* root, int value)
{
    if (!root && !value)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(root)
    {
        return HasPathSum(root->left, value - root->data)
            || HasPathSum(root->right, value - root->data);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I managed to write it after **massive** tinkering. For recursion I was doing

```
HasPathSum(root->left, value - root->data);
return HasPathSum(root->right, value - root->data);
```

To explore all the paths, but it wasn't quite all right because if the path sum was in left, It did go to true but eventually **returned `false`**. I figured I will have to write the recursive definition in a single line for it to work and wrote `||` just as an experiment and it blew my mind that it actually worked. I wrote `std::cout << value << " ";` at the top of `if` statement to see what is happening and it does what its supposed do and stops just as a path has been found.

This is all that I've tried but I am unable too wrap my head around how the recursive function with `||` works or will work if given `&&`.

If someone experienced can provide an explanation! :)

Comment: There's nothing about a recursive call that has anything to do with the `||` operator or the `&&` operator, or any operator used on the return value of that recursive call. What operator is used on the recursive call's results is completely immaterial. Short-circuit evaluation of the `&&` and `||` operator works exactly the same whether the operands are recursive calls, other funciton calls, or something else entirely. One has nothing to do with the other. It is not clear exactly what you're asking. What exactly is your question, or you don't understand, specifically?

Comment: How does the recursion unfolds here `return HasPathSum(root->left, value - root->data) || HasPathSum(root->right, value - root->data);` ?

Comment: What does `||` operator is doing here if not comparing them?

Comment: The `||` operator does not compare anything. Not here, nor in any other expression. It evaluates it's left hand side, then if it evaluates to false, it evaluates the right hand side. So, here, the first recursive call takes place. If it returns a logical true, nothing further happens, otherwise the second recursive call takes place, then. What the `||` operator does here is exactly the same thing it does in any other expression. Do you know what the `||` operator is, and how it works? If so, you just answered your own question. It works exactly the same here.

Comment: The `||` operator doesn't "stop" anything. I double-checked my previous comment, and it is accurate as far as explaining how the `||` operator works. It evaluates its left-hand side, if it is true then the result of the `||` operator is true, and nothing further happens. Otherwise it evaluates its right-hand side, and the result of the `||` operator is the logical value of its right-hand side expression. This is how the `||` operator is explained in every C++ textbook, which part of this explanation is unclear to you?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Pretty much cleared now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator ||` and `operator &&` does short circuit, so might doesn't evaluate second operand depending of the first one.

`bool b = f() || g();` is mostly equivalent to

```
bool b = f();
if (b == false) b = g();
```

`bool b = f() && g();` is mostly equivalent to

```
bool b = f();
if (b == true) b = g();
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340241/how-does-return-statement-return-values-in-recursive-functions-in-javascript) behaves similarly in C++ as well? Nina's answer?

Comment: Yes Javascript and C++ does short-circuit for `||` (logical OR).